# Programmatically click views in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to programmatically send click events to a view? if so, how?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you want to create automated tests you might want to have a look at [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso). Otherwise you can use the [`performClick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()) method.

Comment: Use Espresso now for Android UI tests. https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/

Answer (score 0):

For use in tests take a look at [Robotium](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/).